# Custom post type display

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I work on a website with a custom post type, described in the `functions.php` file of a child theme.

I created a function, still within the functions file, that describes the beahavior of a page for this custom content : basically, to achieve that, I use `get_the_terms()` and `get_post_meta()`, within a function named `add_thecontent()`. It's called with a filter : `add_filter('the_content','add_thecontent');`

It works fine : I can retrieve the name, the custom taxonomies, the several fields...etc.

I also work on another website, still with a custom post type (a different one), with a different theme. I use the same mechanism as stated above (child theme + functions file + content called within a filter) but when I want to display a preview of my custom post, the engine calls the file `content-single.php` of the main theme. This file calls `the_category()` and that leads to warnings in my page, beacuse I don't have a "regular" category for my custom post, only custom taxonomies.

I tried to put a `content-single.php` in my child theme in order to redefine its beahavior, but I get errors. And I think it's not a proper way to proceed.

What I want is to force WP engine to display a custom post as I defined in the functions.php. How can I achieve that ? Thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to install and debug using [Which Template Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/which-template/) once you install this, you can know which file is being called to parse your custom post.

Also, take a look at the worpdress hierarchy page [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

If you created a custom post, the you can create an individual page for that custom post as single-$posttype.php and you would be able to control the flow of the file.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your help ! but why was I able to display my custom post properly in the first case ? Why content-single.php wasn't called here too ?

Comment: I understand that you have two different WP installations, so I would take a look at functions.php to see if any custom content parsing is taking place. If you upload some code I would be able to help you more.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to simplify the code and post it. I tried to rename content-single.php, and it seems to work. Now I'm trying to use the plugin you mentioned in order to find from where this file is called

Comment: when I try to display a custom post page, the plugin "Which template" says that "single.php" is used, though the warnings on my page come from "content-single.php". I created a file named "content-single.php" in my child theme. If i'ts empty, nothing displays. If it contains at least the_content(), it will display the content as it was defined in functions.php. But now the articles and pages don't display properly anymore !

Comment: Remember that the_content() need to be called inside the_loop(): https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action

Comment: Indeed ! the bug comes from the theme I've been using

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In the parent theme, `content-single.php` included the following code :

```
<span class="cat-name"><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></span>
```

So I created a `content-single.php` in my child theme, and I made a test on the type of post. If the post is not a custom post I created, display normally its category. Else, do nothing, because I handle the taxonomies myself.

```
<?php if($post->post_type != 'myCustomPost') {;?>
            <span class="cat-name"><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
```